# How can I implement up and down voting?

Tags: javascript, php, post

If you have used Stack Overflow for a while, you surely have used the function of vote up and down of the question and answer. I notice Stack Overflow uses `<a>` anchor. But I don't know how to POST the data to server. I think it's JavaScript associated with this `<a>`, but I can't find it. How can I implement it?

Comment: I find the question legit, no reason to close.

Comment: search for 'Ajax' on Google, explore, explore and explore and a whole new world opens up for you!

Comment: I'm soverlordooooooooooo relieved we have moderators who can protect us from this horrendous question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, JavaScript is involved. There are two parts: Hooking up a handler for the click events on the voting "buttons", and sending data to the server.

Hooking up the events is well-covered elsewhere and I won't go into it here. (For instance, I cover it in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23799448/157247).)

Sending the data to the server, you can use ajax. On any browser that isn't completely obsolete, you can use `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/path/to/server/destination");
xhr.onreadystatechange = handleStateChange;
xhr.send("id=" + encodeURIComponent(id) +
         "&user=" + encodeURIComponent(userId) +
         "&vote=up");
function handleStateChange() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        // POST complete
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            // POST complete and we have response, check it
            if (xhr.responseText !== "ok") { // Or whatever you want it to be
                // Report problem
            }
        } else {
            // Ajax failed, handle/report problem
        }
    }
}
```

On more up-to-date browsers you can use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch):

```
var body = new FormData();
body.append("id", id);
body.append("user", userId);
body.append("vote", "up");
fetch("/path/to/server/destination", {
    method: "POST",
    body: body
})
.then(function(res) {
    if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + res.status);
    }
    return res.text(); // or `res.json()` if you return JSON
})
.then(function(data) {
    if (data !== "ok") { // Or whatever
        // Report problem
    }
})
.catch(function(error) {
    // Ajax failed, handle/report problem
});
```

Just for fun, here's a complete example:

HTML:

```
<div class="article" data-itemid="427">
<a href="voteup"   class="vote up"  >Up</a>
<a href="votedown" class="vote down">Down</a>
<!-- ...the contents of the item... -->
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    // Regardless of the below, we handle the event, so "consume" it
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get the anchor element
    var voteLink = event.target.closest("a.vote");
    if (!voteLink) {
        // Didn't find one, bail
        return;
    }

    // See if the vote has already been done or is in progress
    if (voteLink.classList.contains("done") || voteLink.classList.contains("inprogress")) {
        // Ignore the click, possibly tell the user why
        return;
    }

    // Get the vote type
    var voteType = voteLink.classList.contains("up") ? "up" : "down";

    // Get the item we"re voting on
    var item = voteLink.closest(".article");

    // Get its ID
    var itemId = item.getAttribute("data-itemid");

    // If we didn"t get an ID...
    if (!itemId) {
        // ...report error
        return;
    }

    // Mark "in progress" and initiate the vote; action continues
    // in our callbacks below
    voteLink.classList.add("inprogress");
    var body = new FormData();
    body.append("itemId", itemId);
    body.append("voteType", voteType);
    fetch("savevote", {
        method: "POST",
        body:   body
    })
    .then(function(res) {
        if (!res.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP error " + res.status);
        }
        return res.text(); // or `res.json()` if you return JSON
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        if (data === "ok") { // Or whatever
            voteLink.classList.add("done");
        } else {
            // Report an error to the user, the server couldn"t record the vote
        }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        // Ajax failed, handle/report problem
    })
    .finally(function() {
        // Not in progress anymore
        voteLink.classList.remove("inprogress");
    });
});
```

Some notes:

- The code above is written in ES5 but you could use ES2015+ features in most modern browsers (or by transpiling with tools like [Babel](https://babeljs.io)).
- I've put an `href` on the links (which StackOverflow doesn't have), so that if JavaScript is disabled, we can fall back to going to a page where we let the user vote using a form submission or something. Also, links with `href` are treated specially by browsers (tab targets, etc.), so this is useful for accessibility. (To really do that, I'd probably have to put the article ID in the `href` as well.)
- I'm storing the ID of the item we're voting on in a [`data-` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes).
- We find the item to vote on by locating the "closest" article to the button that was clicked. The DOM's [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) function starts with the element and examines that element to see if it fits the given CSS selector, then if not looks at its parent, then *its* parent, etc., until it finds a match. So the vote buttons are associated with the article by containment; the article being voted on *contains* the voting buttons.
- If you were rooting the event handler in an element deeper in the page (rather than the document level), you'd probably follow the `closest` check with a [`contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) check to ensure that the element the handler is attached to contains the element that was found (in case it was found in an ancestor element instead). That would be `!voteLink || !this.contains(voteLink)` above (instead of just `!voteLink`).
- I'm using POST because the call changes server state, so GET is inappropriate

Comment: Yes. I know Ajax. But I don't know how stackoverflow's vote up and down associate with ajax. You look into the source code of vote up and down. Its just a "< a >" anchor with no name and id.

Comment: @Magic: I added an example to the answer that may make that a bit clearer.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Comment: @ScottFleming - LOL, wow, this is a *really* old answer, isn't it? :-) jQuery 1.7 was five months away when I wrote it. Thanks for flagging it up. It's late, I'll update tomorrow.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It was enough of an example for me, I have used to to create my own version, which is working perfectly after some adjustments. I can share it if you like.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX).

Answer (score 3):

You can use jquery to do it.
Just apply click eventlisteners on the up/down arrow which will send the data to your server using ajax.

The script on your server will validate the incoming data and update count in the DB.
Then you can send a response back giving the updated count of ups/downs

Note : You'll also have to take into account that a user can only like or dislike once.
You can either handle it at server side / or for simplicity store it in cookie.

Comment: Yes. I know Ajax. But I don't know how stackoverflow's vote up and down associate with ajax. You look into the source code of vote up and down. Its just a "< a >" anchor with no name and id.

Comment: Yeah. if you look at the source then the anchor tag <a> has a class "vote-up-off". You can simply apply a eventlisteners on such anchor tags doing specific things.

Answer (score 0):

Magic is correct, you're looking to use AJAX, which is a technology that allows you to send data back and forth from your page to the server without fully posting the page.

If you'd like a good article to get you started, I'd check out this one at Nettuts:[5 ways to make ajax call with jquery](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/)

In my opinion, using jQuery is the simplest way to post and get data from javascript.

Cheers

Comment: Yes. I know Ajax. But I don't know how stackoverflow's vote up and down associate with ajax. You look into the source code of vote up and down. Its just a "< a >" anchor with no name and id.

Comment: I can see you didn't read that article, Magic. It shows you **exactly** how to hook up ajax calls to DOM elements such as the <a> tag. I guess you were looking for someone else to write your code for you - and you got your wish!

Answer (score 0):

A voting functionality needs two parts:

1. client side
   This one handles the visual part of the voting. You have the buttons which can be a span or a link or an image, or any HTML element. Javascript is used to register an action to that element, so when somebody click up or down the Javascript will know which button was clicked.
2. server side
   In the server side you need to store the logic of the voting. You will need a table where to store the results and to connect a vote to a user and to a certain post in your database. And you will need some functionality related with this voting, for example:

   ```
   function saveVote ($user_id, $post_id) {...}
   // or
   function getPostVotes ($post_id) {...}
   // or
   function getUserVotes ($user_id) {...}
   ```

What connects this 2 parts is as Emil suggested Ajax. Although this is the most common form today, you can use even a simple form or an iframe or other techniques to pass the information to the server. They all do the same thing, which is to pass the voting parameters, like post_id and user_id and vote_result, to a php script that will save them into the database. As an extra step after confirming that the vote is authentic and saved you can increase/decrease the vote count in page.

Comment: Yes. I know Ajax. But I don't know how stackoverflow's vote up and down associate with ajax. You look into the source code of vote up and down. Its just a "< a >" anchor with no name and id.

Comment: the name can be stored in a cookie that is also sent with the request. and remember that events bubble up so another interesting info can come from upper levels. for eaxample prev to a tag is a input hidden with the post value.