# JS li tag onclick not working on IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, addeventlistener

Am using Below JS,but li onclick is not working on IE8 browser.

jsfiddle link :

http://jsfiddle.net/sudheera/DUZ3B/14/

HTML

```
<div class="primaryNav fl">
<ul id="hd_vertical" class="productNav">

<li id="hd_test" class="flight">
<span class="navIcon flightIcon hd_test">Test</span>
<a class="hd_test" href="http://validator.w3.org/">Flights</a>
</li>

<li id="hd_test1" class="bus">
<span class="navIcon busIcon hd_test1">Test</span>
<a class="hd_test1" href="http://www.w3schools.com/">Buses</a>
</li>

</ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
var changeLocation = function(id) {
  var _url = document.getElementsByClassName(id)[1].getAttribute('href');
  location.href = _url;   
}

document.getElementById("hd_vertical").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
        if(e.target.nodeName == "LI") { 
            var _anchor = e.target.id;
            changeLocation(_anchor);
        } else if(e.target.nodeName == "SPAN") {
            var span = e.target;
            var li = span.parentNode;
            var _anchor = li.id;   
            changeLocation(_anchor);
    }
});
```

please suggest

Comment: did you have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769868/addeventlistener-not-working-in-ie8?

Comment: Your code is not compliant with IE8 at all, IE8 does not support `getElementsByClassName`, `addEventListener` etc. You can look up all the native javascript functions on MDN and see what browsers they are supported in.

Comment: @adeneo thanks for u r reply,I tried different code for li onclik,but this is the best one I got.please suggest if any other JS for li onclick : it should take care of inside span,anchor tag and browser compatibility.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IE8 and earlier don't have `addEventListener`, but they do have its non-standard predecessor, `attachEvent`. They're not *quite* the same.

Here's a "hook this event" function that uses what's available:

```
var hookEvent = (function() {
    var div;

    // The function we use on standard-compliant browsers
    function standardHookEvent(element, eventName, handler) {
        element.addEventListener(eventName, handler, false);
        return element;
    }

    // The function we use on browsers with the previous Microsoft-specific mechanism
    function oldIEHookEvent(element, eventName, handler) {
        element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, function(e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            e.preventDefault = oldIEPreventDefault;
            e.stopPropagation = oldIEStopPropagation;
            handler.call(element, e);
        });
        return element;
    }

    // Polyfill for preventDefault on old IE
    function oldIEPreventDefault() {
        this.returnValue = false;
    }

    // Polyfill for stopPropagation on old IE
    function oldIEStopPropagation() {
        this.cancelBubble = true;
    }

    // Return the appropriate function; we don't rely on document.body
    // here just in case someone wants to use this within the head
    div = document.createElement('div');
    if (div.addEventListener) {
        div = undefined;
        return standardHookEvent;
    }
    if (div.attachEvent) {
        div = undefined;
        return oldIEHookEvent;
    }
    throw "Neither modern event mechanism (addEventListener nor attachEvent) is supported by this browser.";
})();
```

Then you'd use it like this in your example:

```
hookEvent(document.getElementById("hd_vertical"), "click", function(e) {
    // ...
});
```

Note how it provides the missing `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` functions on the event object on browsers using `attachEvent` and ensures that `this` within the handler call is what it would be if you were using `addEventListener`.

There are various aspects of event normalization that the above does **not** do:

1. It doesn't guarantee the order in which the handlers will run (`attachEvent` does them in the opposite order to `addEventListener`)
2. It doesn't handle issues around `e.which` vs. `e.keyCode` and such

...and of course, I haven't provided a *detach* event function. :-) For things like that, look at using a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries).

---

Side note: As [adeneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965051/adeneo) pointed out in a comment on the question, IE8 also doesn't support `getElementsByClassName`. But it *does* support `querySelectorAll` and `querySelector`, so change:

```
var _url = document.getElementsByClassName(id)[1].getAttribute('href');
```

to

```
var _url = document.querySelectorAll("." + id)[1].getAttribute('href');
```

Note that that will try to get the *second* element matching the selector. `[1]` is the second entry in the list, not the first, which would be `[0]`. If you meant the first, you can use `querySelector`, which returns just the first match:

```
var _url = document.querySelector("." + id).getAttribute('href');
```

Comment: @Neo - I like to call it *in*compatibility mode. ;-) Sure, I can't see why not, it looks at what's defined and in (in)compatibility mode, IE11 hobbles itself and doesn't define `addEventListener`...