# Click HTML element A and add Class on B with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, class

I can't see what I'm doing wrong here.. Can anyone help please?

JavaScript:

```
function toggleMainNav() {
        var navLink = document.getElementsByClassName('nav_link')[0];
        var mainNav = navLink.nextSibling;
        if ( mainNav.className.match(/(?:^|\s)inactive(?!\S)/) ){
            mainNav.className = 'active';
        } else{
            mainNav.className = 'inactive';
        }
    }

    document.getElementsByClassName('nav_link')[0].addEventListener( 'click' , toggleMainNav );
```

this is the HTML:

```
<a class="nav_link">☰ Menu</a>
<ul class="inactive">
</ul>
```

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: hi dear friends add your code in jsfiddle [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: **If using modern browsers only**, you may also consider `element.classList.contains("someClassName")` instead of a regEx. `element.classList` has a number of nice (read: useful) member functions. Much nicer to work with than `element.className` directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nextSibling` will be a text node containing whitespace. Either scan until you get `nodeType === 1` or use `nextElementSibling` (but check whether it's supported on your target browsers).

---

Side note: `getElementsByClassName` has worse support than `querySelector` / `querySelectorAall` (IE8 has the latter but not the former, for instance), so you might consider using those instead.

Side note 2: IE8 also doesn't have `addEventListener`.

Side note 3: If you hook up your handler via `addEventListener`, within the handler `this` will already be the first `nav_link`, so you don't have to look it up again.

Side note 4: Some older browsers will fail if you don't give the third argument to `addEventListener` (it didn't used to be optional). To be broadly-compatible, be sure to include the `false` at the end.

Comment: Thanks! Clear answer.

Comment: Is it better to avoid using addEventListener and add a onclick attribute?

Comment: @PepijnGieles: No, because using `onclick` means you can't have multiple handlers on the same element. But if you need to support IE8 or earlier, you have to work around the fact that it doesn't have it. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23799448/157247) shows one way to do that.

Comment: By the way, I need this action only to happen on mobile devices. Since it's to show/hide the menu. Do you know where I can find the addEventListener support for those browsers?

Comment: @PepijnGieles: http://caniuse.com has a very good database, but doesn't have a page on `addEventListener`. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) suggests reasonable support. Side note: I've added a fourth "side note" to the answer. :-)

Comment: @TJCrowder Thanks for the tips, I knew about canIuse but indeed couldn't find it.