# How to make on submit form in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried to search it but no favorable results found.

I don't use JQuery and I want to make it with pure JavaScript. I want to make the same as `<form onsubmit="somefunction();">` but directly from JavaScript.

Something like:

```
if(document.getElementById("myid").ISSUBMIT) {
    somefunction();
}
```

in Jquery I can make it with `on.submit`, but how to do in JavaScript?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: you want to call a function on form submit???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get a reference to the form element, and then either:

1. Assign a function to `onsubmit`

   ```
   theFormElement.onsubmit = function() { /* ... */ };
   ```

   or
2. Use `addEventListener` / `attachEvent` to hook the `submit` event. If you don't need IE8 support, you can just use `addEventListener`:

   ```
   theFormElement.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
       // your code here
   }, false);
   ```

   If you also need IE8 support, you probably want to use a function that handles the fact that IE8 uses `attachEvent` instead of `addEventListener`, such as the one in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23799448/157247).

To get a reference to the form, you can use an `id` on the form and use `document.getElementById`, or (on any modern browser, and even IE8) you can use `document.querySelector` and any CSS selector that will find the form.

Comment: Just remember that most browsers are case sensitive when selecting the id (I think IE isn't)

Answer (score 5):

You can use JavaScript's "onsubmit" event.

Html:

```
<form id="my-id">
    // elements
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var form = document.getElementById( 'my-id' );
form.onsubmit = function(){
    // your code
};
```