# JavaScript remove dynamically created tr

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have a js function that adds a `tr` to a `table`:

```
function AddData() {

    var rows = "";

    var product_id = $('input[name="product_name"]').val();

    var product_price = $('input[name="product_price"]').val();

    rows += "<td><input type='hidden' name='item_id[]' value='" + product_id + "'><p>" + name + "</p></td><td><input type='hidden' name='price[]' value='" + product_price + "' class='price'></td><td>&pound;<span id='amount' class='amount'>0</span></td><td><div class='btn btn-circle' onclick='RemoveData()' value='" + curtainid + "'>Delete</div></td>";
    var tbody = document.querySelector("#myTable tbody");
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");

    tr.innerHTML = rows;
    tbody.appendChild(tr)

    update_amounts();    
}
```

Within the `<td>` is a `RemoveData()` call. I want this to remove the selected `tr` from the table. I have tried to use:

```
function RemoveData() {

    var elements = document.getElementById('tr');
    last = elements[elements.length-1];

    last.parentNode.removeChild(last);

}
```

but with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementById` gets a single element, by its `id`. You're passing in a tag name and expecting it to return a list.

If your goal is to remove the last `tr` element anywhere on the page, you can use `querySelectorAll` instead:

```
function RemoveData() {

    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('tr'); // <== Main change
    var last = elements[elements.length-1];         // <== Note I added `var`
    last.parentNode.removeChild(last);
}
```

`querySelectorAll` works on [all modern browsers, and IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector).

---

I added `var` to the `last` line because your code was falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) without it.

---

Re your comment below:

> How would I remove a selected element...

I'd probably have a single event handler on the table and then trigger removal based on the event's target (e.g., delegated handling). That looks something like this:

```js
"use strict";

var tbody = document.getElementById("the-tbody");

// Add rows when the button is clicked
document.getElementById("btn-add").addEventListener("click", addRow, false);
function addRow(e) {
  var row = document.createElement('tr');
  row.innerHTML = '<td>Hi there ' +
      Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) +
      ' <span class="remove">[x]</span></td>';
  tbody.appendChild(row);
}

// Remove rows when their ".remove" span is clicked
tbody.addEventListener("click", removeRow, false);
function removeRow(e) {
  var elm;
  for (elm = e.target; elm !== this; elm = elm.parentNode) {
    if (/\bremove\b/.test(elm.className)) { // On modern browsers you could use `classList`
      // It's a remove link, remove its parent tr and we're done
      removeElement(elm.parentNode);
      e.stopPropagation();
      return;
    }
  }
}

function removeElement(elm) {
  elm.parentNode.removeChild(elm);
}
```

```css
.remove {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="the-tbody"></tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" id="btn-add" value="Add Row">
```

There I'm using `addEventListener`. If you need to support older browsers, you can use the `hookEvent` function in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23799448/157247) instead.

Comment: Thanks TJ, that works well to remove the last element. How would I remove a selected element. For example if I had 3 rows in the table and I wanted to remove the 2nd? How can I pass "this" into the length-1 ?

Comment: @tomantford: I'd probably have a single event handler on the table and then trigger removal based on the event's target (e.g., delegated handling). I can add a quick example.

Comment: TJ - what function should this be wrapped in? I've tried to put it in $().ready(function() but neither var - product_id or product_price are sent through

Comment: I think because my button is dynamically generated I need to use jquery find?

Answer (score -1):

I prefer the jQuery function `.closest()` to delete the selected row so you don't need to work with an Row-ID...because the threadstarter has already jQuery...try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button[name=deleteTR]').click(function(){
 $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td><button type="button" name="deleteTR">Delete</button></td><td>Row 1</td></tr>
  <tr><td><button type="button" name="deleteTR">Delete</button></td><td>Row 2</td></tr>
  <tr><td><button type="button" name="deleteTR">Delete</button></td><td>Row 3</td></tr>
  <tr><td><button type="button" name="deleteTR">Delete</button></td><td>Row 4</td></tr>
</table>
```

Greetings from Vienna