# How to get updated height and width in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How can I constantly get the width and the height of the browser via javascript? Simply using `document.body.clientWidth` or `window.innerWidth` gives the width once the page is loaded.

However, how can one obtain the width and height updated whenever the user resizes the window?

Answer (score 1):

> but is it possible to get the width and height updated when the user resize the window.

Yes, using the `resize` event:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    // Now, clientWidth and innerWidth and such have changed
}, false);
```

(There I'm using `addEventListener`. If you need to support older browsers, you can use the `hookEvent` function in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23799448/157247) instead.)

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the dimensions on resize or on [requestAnimationFrame](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/)

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    ...
};
```

Comment: after resizing it gets the new size but page doesn't load.