# Avoid onclick from parent

Tags: javascript

Is there a way for the following sample:

```
<tr id="x" onclick="do_something()">
    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
    <td>
       <a href="javascript:;" onclick="do_something_else()">CANCEL</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

when clicking CANCEL link not to execute both do_something() and do_something_else().

I only need to execute do_something_else()

Thank you

Comment: you have to stop the event from bubbling up. use stopPropagation inside do_something_else. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation

Comment: can you show me how please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options for you:

- The Minimum Change
- The Modern Way

#### The Minimum Change

In the `onXYZ` attribute, your code is effectively within a function that has an `event` variable (directly on most browsers, a global on older IE), so if you pass that into your function, you can call `stopPropagation` on it (if it has that function) or use `cancelBubble` if it doesn't (old IE):

```js
function do_something() {
  snippet.log("do_something called");
}
function do_something_else(event) {
  snippet.log("do_something_else called");
  if (event.stopPropagation) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  } else {
    event.cancelBubble = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="x" onclick="do_something()">
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="do_something_else(event)">CANCEL</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

#### The Modern Way

Using `onXYZ` attributes is fairly old-fashioned these days. Instead, consider hooking up your handlers in a modern way, which gives you the `stopPropagation()` function:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("x");
x.addEventListener("click", do_something, false);
x.querySelector("a").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  do_something_else();
}, false);

function do_something() {
  snippet.log("do_something called");
}
function do_something_else() {
  snippet.log("do_something_else called");
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="x">
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>
        <a href="javascript:;">CANCEL</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you need to support IE8, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23799448/157247) gives you a function to handle the fact that IE8 doesn't support `addEventListener` (but does have its Microsoft-specific predecessor, `attachEvent`).