# CSS Style manipulation : Javascript not Working

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouseevent, onmouseover

i Was trying to make a simple button which changes colour on mouse over using JavaScript and its not working so,help please....
html:

```
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Button.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Button.js"></script>
<title>BUTTON</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Button">PRESS ME</div>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
var Button = document.getElementById('Button');
Button.onmouseover(function(){
this.style.backgroundColor  = 'rgba(0,255,0,0.3)';
});
```

CSS:

```
#Button{
width: 120px;
height : 30px;
position: fixed;
top: 100px;
left:300px;
border: 1px solid black;
background-color : rgba(0,0,255,0.3);
font-size : 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
 Button.onmouseover(function(){
   this.style.backgroundColor  = 'rgba(0,255,0,0.3)';
 });
```

to

```
   Button.onmouseover = function(){
       this.style.backgroundColor  = 'rgba(0,255,0,0.3)';
    };
```

Full example:

```js
var Button = document.getElementById('Button');
Button.onmouseover = function () {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,255,0,0.3)';
};
```

```css
#Button {
    width: 120px;
    height : 30px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    left:300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color : rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3);
    font-size : 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Button">PRESS ME</div>
```

**JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/n4j53jcu/**

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing two different paradigms of hooking events. `onmouseover` is a property you can assign a single function to, via assignment (not calling it). So you *could* do:

```
Button.onmouseover = function(){
    this.style.backgroundColor  = 'rgba(0,255,0,0.3)';
};
```

```js
var Button = document.getElementById('Button');
Button.onmouseover = function(){
  this.style.backgroundColor  = 'rgba(0,255,0,0.3)';
};
```

```css
#Button{
width: 120px;
height : 30px;
position: fixed;
top: 100px;
left:300px;
border: 1px solid black;
background-color : rgba(0,0,255,0.3);
font-size : 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Button">PRESS ME</div>
```

But the modern way is to play nicely with others and not bludgeon any previous handler (which the above does), but just add to the handler list:

```
Button.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    this.style.backgroundColor  = 'rgba(0,255,0,0.3)';
}, false);
```

```js
var Button = document.getElementById('Button');
Button.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
  this.style.backgroundColor  = 'rgba(0,255,0,0.3)';
}, false);
```

```css
#Button{
width: 120px;
height : 30px;
position: fixed;
top: 100px;
left:300px;
border: 1px solid black;
background-color : rgba(0,0,255,0.3);
font-size : 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Button">PRESS ME</div>
```

Of course, IE8 and earlier make that difficult, but you can use the function in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23799448/157247) if you need to support them.