# Key-Press event listener when checking textarea input in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, keypress, addeventlistener

I want to check two conditions for every button press on the keyboard inside a `textarea`:

1) If it's a number then add it to the text area.

2) If it's anything else push an alert to the user.

The `textarea` tag in the html is:

```
<textarea id="input" placeholder="EnterInput"></textarea>
```

What I wrote inside the JS file is:

```
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("keypress", checkInput(e));
function checkInput(keyPressed){
    if(keyPressed < 48 || keyPressed > 57){
        alert("Wrong input! The charcted entered is not a number.");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for what? whats the problem, whats not working?

Comment: so whats the problem

Comment: So you catch keypresses. BUT what if they paste?

Comment: An entire *textarea* of just digits? Unusual...

Comment: I want to prevent from adding the charcter in case of not a number character.

Comment: T.J Crowder i built an calculator that can have the numbers entered to a textarea.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery

Answer (score 4):

You're immediately invoking your listener function by having the `()`

```
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("keypress", checkInput(e))
                                                                         ^^ INVOKED!
```

`event` will automatically be passed to your function, so simply omit that:

```
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("keypress", checkInput)
```

Also, the `which` property of `event` stores the key code (on most browsers, as @TJCrowder pointed out, older browsers may use the `keyCode` property):

```
function checkInput(event) {
    var keyCode = event.hasOwnProperty('which') ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    //Now check
}
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Good to know.. I often forget about older browsers :\ - updating answer.

Comment: how do i block the character from being inserted to the textarea value in case of not a number?

Comment: @user3126715: On modern browsers: `event.preventDefault();` On older IE: `event.returnValue = false;`. So `if (event.preventDefault) { event.preventDefault(); } else { event.returnValue = false; }` Or use `hookEvent` from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23799448/157247) and you can always rely on `event.preventDefault();`