# javascript keydown shortcut function but ignore if in text box

Tags: javascript

I have set a one key skip/change page function.
but when user want to type "0" in input text or text area, the one key function also effect and change to another page.

How can i ignore this java script when user using text input or text area?

```
document.onkeydown=nextpage; 
function nextpage(){
  var event=document.all?window.event:arguments[0]; 
  if (event.keyCode==13) location="#skipcontent"; 
  if (event.keyCode==48) location="contact-us.php";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Examine the `target` element to see what element the event was targeting:

```
document.onkeydown=nextpage; 
function nextpage(e){
  var event = document.all ? window.event : e;
  switch (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase()) {
    case "input":
    case "textarea":
    case "select":
    case "button":
    // ...and so on for other elements you want to exclude;
    // list of current elements here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#elements-1
      break;
    default:
      if (event.keyCode==13) location="#skipcontent"; 
      if (event.keyCode==48) location="contact-us.php";
      break;
  }
}
```

Or instead of a `switch`, you could use a regular expression with an alternation:

```
document.onkeydown=nextpage; 
function nextpage(e){
  var event = document.all ? window.event : e;
  if (!/^(?:input|textarea|select|button)$/i.test(e.target.tagName)) {
    if (event.keyCode==13) location="#skipcontent"; 
    if (event.keyCode==48) location="contact-us.php";
  }
}
```

---

Side note: You might look at using `addEventListener`, which is supported on all modern browsers and allows for multiple handlers per event per element. If you have to support IE8, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23799448/157247) has a function you can use which falls back to `attachEvent` and handles the event object shuffle for you.