# Anchor tag reloading the page instead of handling onclick in IE

Tags: javascript, html

My anchor tag is

```
<a onclick="redirectCHUB(); return false;" target="_blank" href="#">
```

It reloads the current page in another tab and do not run the function.

I have tried `href="javascript:void(0)"` also.
It reloads the javscript:void(0) in another tab.

I am using href because it doesn't work as a link in IE 9 ,10.

P.S: redirectCHUB() is a POST request Ajax call whose success will redirect to page in another tab

Comment: It's unrelated to the problem, but why would you put `target="_blank"` on a link you intend will never be followed?

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the web console of your browser, you'll probably see an error saying that `redirectCHUB` is not defined. Since the function call fails (throws an exception), the `return false` is never executed, and the default action isn't prevented.

To call a function from an attribute event handler, it has to be a **global** function. (This is one of many reasons not to use them, see below for an alternative.)

If the function **is** a global, that attribute works:

```js
function redirectCHUB() {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = "redirectCHUB ran";
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

```html
<a onclick="redirectCHUB(); return false;" target="_blank" href="#">click me</a>
```

To use a non-global function (which is preferred), use advanced event handling hookup. To do that, you'll need a way to identify the anchor you want to add the handler to. That can be any CSS selector; `id`s are handy but of course limited (they have to be unique on the page) and a bit inflexible.

Using modern event handling still requires allowing for older versions of IE that use Microsoft's `attachEvent` instead of `addEventListener`; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23799448/157247) has a fully-implemented cross-browser means of doing it.

Here's an example using that `hookEvent` function:

```js
// The hookEvent function; you obviously just stick this off in a
// library file or some such...
var hookEvent = (function() {
  var div;

  // The function we use on standard-compliant browsers
  function standardHookEvent(element, eventName, handler) {
    element.addEventListener(eventName, handler, false);
    return element;
  }

  // The function we use on browsers with the previous Microsoft-specific mechanism
  function oldIEHookEvent(element, eventName, handler) {
    element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, function(e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      e.preventDefault = oldIEPreventDefault;
      e.stopPropagation = oldIEStopPropagation;
      handler.call(element, e);
    });
    return element;
  }

  // Polyfill for preventDefault on old IE
  function oldIEPreventDefault() {
    this.returnValue = false;
  }

  // Polyfill for stopPropagation on old IE
  function oldIEStopPropagation() {
    this.cancelBubble = true;
  }

  // Return the appropriate function; we don't rely on document.body
  // here just in case someone wants to use this within the head
  div = document.createElement('div');
  if (div.addEventListener) {
    div = undefined;
    return standardHookEvent;
  }
  if (div.attachEvent) {
    div = undefined;
    return oldIEHookEvent;
  }
  throw "Neither modern event mechanism (addEventListener nor attachEvent) is supported by this browser.";
})();

// Note that this code must be in a script tag AFTER the link;
// best place is right at the end, just before the closing </body>
// tag
(function() {
  // This scoping function ensures our functions aren't globals,
  // to demonstrate using non-globals
  
  // Our click handler
  hookEvent(
    document.getElementById("the-link"),
    "click",
    function(e) {
      redirectCHUB();
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  );
  
  // Target function
  function redirectCHUB() {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = "redirectCHUB ran";
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  }
})();
```

```html
<a id="the-link" target="_blank" href="#">click me</a>
```