# How can I pass an id as a parameter to a function?

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML page with the following code:

```
<input type="number" maxlength="5" id="patrollerID.1.1" placeholder="ID Num" onchange="getPatroller(this.id)" />
```

I would like to move the JavaScript out of the html. The id changes based on change events. How can I keep all of the JavaScript in my .js file instead of inline?

Here is what I have:

```
function getPatroller(patroller) {
    var element = document.getElementById(patroller);
    /** @type {Date} */
    var date = new Date();
    /** @const */
    var ID = 2,
        LAST = 0,
        FIRST = 1,
        LEVEL = 3;
    /** @type {number} */
    var exists = 0;
    /** @type {string} */
    var level;
    /** @type {Array.<string>} */
    var elementId = patroller.split('.');
    for (var j = 0; j < patrollers.length; j++) {
        if (element.value == patrollers[j][ID]) {
            document.getElementById("patroller." + elementId[1] + "." + elementId[2]).innerHTML = "<h4>" + patrollers[j][FIRST] + " " + patrollers[j][LAST] + "</h4>";
            if (patrollers[j][LEVEL] == 1) {
                level = "Basic";
            } else if (patrollers[j][LEVEL] == 2) {
                level = "Senior";
            } else {
                level = "Certified";
            }
            document.getElementById("level." + elementId[1] + "." + elementId[2]).innerHTML = "<h4>" + level + "</h4>";
            var minutes = date.getMinutes();
            if (minutes < 10) {
                minutes = "0" + minutes;
            }
            document.getElementById("time." + elementId[1] + "." + elementId[2]).innerHTML = "<h4>" + date.getHours() + ":" + minutes + "</h4>";
            patrollers.splice(patrollers[j]--, 1); //remove array element
            elementId[2]++;
            /** @type {boolean} */
            var addTeam = setCounter(elementId[1]);
            if (addTeam === true) {
                addPatroller(elementId[1], elementId[2]);
            }
            exists = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (exists == 0) {
        alert("PLEASE TRY AGAIN!");//Do something here if number already in use.
        element.value = '';
    }
}

function setCounter(teamNum) {
    /** @const */
    var MAX_TEAM = 4;
    if (teamNum == 1) {
        if (typeof t1Counter == 'undefined') {
            t1Counter = 1;
        }
        if (t1Counter < MAX_TEAM) {
            t1Counter++;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (teamNum == 2) {
        if (typeof t2Counter == 'undefined') {
            t2Counter = 1;
        }
        if (t2Counter < MAX_TEAM) {
            t2Counter++;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (teamNum == 3) {
        if (typeof t3Counter == 'undefined') {
            t3Counter = 1;
        }
        if (t3Counter < MAX_TEAM) {
            t3Counter++;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (teamNum == 4) {
        if (typeof t4Counter == 'undefined') {
            t4Counter = 1;
        }
        if (t4Counter < MAX_TEAM) {
            t4Counter++;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }  else {
        if (typeof t5Counter == 'undefined') {
            t5Counter = 1;
        }
        if (t5Counter < MAX_TEAM) {
            t5Counter++;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: @ScarletMerlin: ***ugh*** [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) at least.

Comment: @ScarletMerlin no insults here, please.

Comment: I know how to do static id's, just not dynamic id's....

Answer (score 0):

You use `addEventListener`, or `attachEvent` on older IE (IE8 and before).

In this case:

```
document.getElementById("patrollerID.1.1").addEventListener("change", function() {
    // Here, `this` refers to the element, so:
    getPatroller(this.id);
}, false);
```

[This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23799448/157247) has a `hookEvent` function you can use if you need to support older IE and don't want to use a DOM library like jQuery.

---

Re your comment:

> I don't know if I'm being clear: The id changes for each change event, i.e. patrollerID.1.1 changes to patrollerID.1.2, etc

I think you mean, there are multiple elements with different `id`s, rather than that the `id` changes. :-)

In that case, you have two options:

1. Use `querySelectorAll` (which returns a list) with a valid CSS selector that will select the elements (`[id^=patroller]`, for instance, or perhaps something structural, or give them a class) and loop through the resulting list using `addEventListener` on each entry as above.
2. Or, hook the `change` event on an element that *contains* all of these inputs, accept the event argument in your handler function, and look at the `target` property on it — that will be the input where the change occurred. This is called "event delegation."

Here's an `addEventListener`-only example of #2:

```js
// Hook `change` on the container:
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  // Is it a patroller?
  if (e.target && e.target.id && e.target.id.substring(0, 9) === "patroller") {
    // yes
    alert("Patroller " + e.target.id + " changed to " + e.target.value);
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    We care about these inputs, so when you change them, you'll see an alert:
    <br><input type="text" id="patroller1">
    <input type="text" id="patroller2">
    <input type="text" id="patroller3">
  </div>
  <div>
    We don't care about these ones, changing them doesn't do anything:
    <br><input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know if I'm being clear: The id changes for each change event, i.e. patrollerID.1.1 changes to patrollerID.1.2, etc...