# acessing innerHTML text node inside a block of HTML

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml

I'm trying to access the 12:00 number in this huge span of HTML.  It's in the `<div id = gameClock>`. I tried using `getElementById().innerHTML` of the div, and then `console log` with a function that fires on click of the element, gives me nothing, no error either

```js
function minusMinute() {
  time = window.document.getElementById('gameClock').innerHTML;
  console.log(time);
}

minusMinute = window.document.getElementById('minusMinute');

minusMinute.addEventListener('click', minusMinute, false);
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="text-center small-12 small-centered columns">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="gameClock" class=" small-6 small-centered columns">
        <span class='clockButtons badge primary' id='minusMinute'><i class='fi-minus'></i></span><span class='clockButtons badge primary'><i onClick='minusMinute'class='fi-plus'></i></span><span id='gameTime'>12:00</span><span class='clockButtons badge primary'><i class='fi-minus'></i></span>
        <span
        class='clockButtons badge primary'><i class='fi-plus'></i>
          </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple issues there:

- You've declared a function called `minusMinute`, but you've also declared a *variable* called `minusMinute`, and assigning to it overwrites the function. So your

  ```
  minusMinute.addEventListener('click', minusMinute, false);
  ```

  line is hooking up the *element* as a click handler.
- Your HTML also has `onclick="minusMinute"`. If `minusMinute` *were* a function, that wouldn't do anything, because the function the browser creates to wrap your code there will just refer to `minusMinute` but not call it. `onXyz` attribute handlers should contain function calls (e.g., `onclick="minusMinute()"`), but if you're using `addEventListener`, you don't need the `onclick` attribute at all.
- While it's true that the 12:00 is inside an element with `id="gameClock"`, there a lot *else* in there as well. But helpfully it's all on its own inside the span with `id="gameTime"`.

Here's a fixed version with minimal changes:

```js
function minusMinute(){
  var time = window.document.getElementById('gameTime').innerHTML;
  console.log(time);
}

window.document.getElementById('minusMinute').addEventListener('click', minusMinute, false);
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="text-center small-12 small-centered columns">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="gameClock"class=" small-6 small-centered columns">
        <span class='clockButtons badge primary' id='minusMinute'><i class='fi-minus'>minusMinuteIsHere</i></span><span class='clockButtons badge primary'><i class='fi-plus'></i></span><span id='gameTime'>12:00</span><span class='clockButtons badge primary'><i class='fi-minus'></i></span><span class='clockButtons badge primary'><i class='fi-plus'></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Changes:

1. I don't declare a `minusMinute` variable and assign to it, so the `minusMinute` function doesn't get overwritten.
2. I removed the `onclick` attribute
3. I used `gameTime` rather than `gameClock`
4. Just for the purposes of the snippet, I put some text inside the `minusMinute` element, since the snippet doesn't have your CSS and so there's no icon to click.

---

Side note: There's no need for `window.document`, just use `document`. `window` is a global variable (pointing to the global object, where most global variables are available as properties), and `document` is a global variable, so... I mean, you could also do `window.window.document`, or `window.window.window.document`. :-)

Comment: Thanks T.J.  I didnt realize the minusMinute var and function would conflict.  all i had to do was change the handler to minusMinuteBtn and all worked!!

Comment: Your code will not work on all js enabled browsers. Mine will.

Comment: @mplungjan: You mean the `addEventListener` thing? Yes, obsolete browsers don't have it. As the OP was using it, and the question had nothing to do with it, I didn't bother to change it. Note that `onclick` is *another* not-best-practices approach, as it doesn't play nicely with others. If you want to demonstrate cross-browser compatibility, [do it thoroughly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23799448/157247).

Comment: No. I do not agree. On click works and is a perfectly OK event handler. IE 8 is still hugely in use - especially in some corporations

Comment: @mplungjan: Yes, IE8 still has significant use, which is why I say be thorough and demonstrate modern event handling.

Comment: Truly modern is $(...).on("click")

Comment: @mplungjan: Oh for crying out loud. People have perfectly valid reasons for sometimes not using libraries. I'm so done with this.

Comment: You started the "very poor advice" that irked me no end

Comment: @mplungjan: Well, I'm sorry then. It's very well-established that using `onload` **just** to wait until the DOM is parsed is an anti-pattern. If you want to get all bent out of shape for my observing that, that's your call.

Comment: I'm not that bent. You're the one crying out loud ;))))

Answer (score 1):

Like mplungjan already mentioned, you should make sure the element is there when you try to get it's content (either by including the javascript at the end or using the onload function).

another problem that you also had is you used the same name for global variable minusMinute and the function name minusMinute so that would produce you the also give you an error.

Answer (score 0):

You firstly need to do this when the Dom elements exist, for example onload :

```
window.onload=function() {
  var minusMinute = window.document.getElementById('minusMinute');
  minusMinute.addEventListener('click', minusMinute, false);
}
```

or simpler and more compatible - I assume you want gameTime instead of gameClock

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById('minusMinute').onclick=function() {
    var time = document.getElementById('gameTime').innerHTML;
    console.log(time);
  }
}
```

The above anonymous function also solves a name clash between your function and object.

You also have some weird onclicks in the html that needs to be removed,
Lastly addEventListener is not compatible with all browsers.

Here is my code with your cleaned up HTML - I had to add some content to minusMinute to see it

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('minusMinute').onclick = function() {
    var time = document.getElementById('gameTime').textContent;
    console.log(time);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="text-center small-12 small-centered columns">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="gameClock" class=" small-6 small-centered columns">
        <span class='clockButtons badge primary' id='minusMinute'><i class='fi-minus'><<</i></span>
        <span class='clockButtons badge primary'><i class='fi-plus'>>></i></span>
        <span id='gameTime'>12:00</span><span class='clockButtons badge primary'><i class='fi-minus'></i></span>
        <span class='clockButtons badge primary'><i class='fi-plus'></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: He'd be gtting an error if that were the case. Anyway, there are several *other* issues. And `onload` is **really late** in the process. Better to simply put the script at the bottom of the page.

Comment: *"You firstly need to do this onload:"* No, he doesn't, and it's very poor advice. One need only ensure that the script tag is below the tags for the elements on which it operates (best practice is just before the closing `</body>` tag).

Comment: How so poor advise? It works fantastically - surely just your opinion here :/

Comment: I changed the wording - better?

Comment: "*surely just your opinion here"* No, look around, it's **the standard** advice (such as [the YUI guidelines](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom), some of the best-respected guidelines on the 'net). Waiting until `onload` means your page sits there in front of the user without the code having run for the entire time **all* subsidiary resources (images, etc.) load.

Comment: *Slightly* better. Still suggests a well-known anti-pattern, but it's no longer actually wrong.

Comment: That may be an issue or it may not be an issue. Poor advice is very strong. Suited me fine for 20 years. Perhaps I just have fast loading pages