# changing an image when hover with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Title.

I've seen a lot of ways of doing it when the `IMG` element is used :

```
<img src="blah" id="get" onmouseover="newImage()" onmouseout="oldImage()
```

Javavscript

```
function newImage() { document.getElementById(get").src="blah2"}
function oldImage() { document.getElementById("get").src="blah"}
```

But I keep my images on CSS as `background-image: url()` inside an id:

```
<div id="image"
```

How I apply the same principle but when images are on CSS and its on a `div` `id`

NEW TO JAVASCRIPT PLEASE NO FRAMEWORKS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need JavaScript for this (but I give a JavaScript alternative below), just use CSS's `:hover` pseudo-class.

```
#get {
    background-image: url(/path/to/image/when/not/hovering.png);
}
#get:hover {
    background-image: url(/path/to/image/when/hovering.png);
}
```

Example: This div shows your user icon normally, then shows mine if you hover it:

```css
#get {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url(https://graph.facebook.com/950389301719024/picture?type=small);
}
#get:hover {
  background-image: url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ca3e484c121268e4c8302616b2395eb9?s=50&d=identicon&r=PG
);
}
```

```html
<div id="get"></div>
```

But if you really *want* to use JavaScript, it's very similar to the code you've quoted, you just change `.style.backgroundImage` on your element instead of changing `.src`:

```js
function startHover(element) {
  element.style.backgroundImage = "url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ca3e484c121268e4c8302616b2395eb9?s=50&d=identicon&r=PG)";
}
function stopHover(element) {
  element.style.backgroundImage = "url(https://graph.facebook.com/950389301719024/picture?type=small)";
}
```

```css
#get {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="get" style="background-image: url(https://graph.facebook.com/950389301719024/picture?type=small)" onmouseover="startHover(this)" onmouseout="stopHover(this)"></div>
```

But I discourage use of `onxyz` attributes; use modern event handling instead:

```js
(function() {
  var div = document.getElementById("get");
  div.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    div.style.backgroundImage = "url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ca3e484c121268e4c8302616b2395eb9?s=50&d=identicon&r=PG)";
  }, false);
  div.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    div.style.backgroundImage = "url(https://graph.facebook.com/950389301719024/picture?type=small)";
  }, false);
})();
```

```css
#get {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="get" style="background-image: url(https://graph.facebook.com/950389301719024/picture?type=small)"></div>
```

That uses `addEventListener`, which is supported by all modern browsers (not by IE8, or IE9-IE11 in their broken "compatibility" mode). If you need to support those, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23799448/157247) has a function you can use for cross-browser event handling without a library.

Comment: Alright nailed it . but for the sake of knowledge how would one do so with javascript using the example above as template?

Comment: @blueHorse if u want to do in JavaScript then you can have two CSS classes with different background images. Then on mouse over addthe other class to the element. On mouse out remove that class.

Comment: @BlueHorse: I've added that. Rajesh's approach is also very good, as it keeps your image paths and such in CSS rather than in code.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You are a good man! many thanks for taking the time.