# Why doesn't this onclick handler on an img work?

Tags: javascript, html

I use a `<img>`, set `onclick()` method, but it cannot call the method:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Date</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 300px; height: 200px;" id="img-div" >
    <img id="img-id"  src="resources/01.jpg" width="200px" height="80px"  style="CURSOR:pointer;" onclick="close();"> 
</div>
<script  type="text/javascript">
    function close(){

        console.log('js');

        alert(111);
    }

</script>
</body>
<html>
```

Why when I click the `<img>`, it can not execute the `close()` cody?
I really don't know how to resolve the issue.

Comment: Since `window.close()` is already defined by the browser (for closing the current window), you better change `close()` to `somethingElse()`

Comment: @haim770 Nice, your answer is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a function named `close` on the global context (`window`, in case of the browser), you're actually defining it as `window.close`. But, since `window.close` is reserved for the purpose of closing the current window, they collide.

Change the name to something less generic:

```
function closeIt() {
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 3):

As haim770 pointed out in a comment *(edit; and now [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39326775/157247))*, the problem is the name of the function. The global namespace is really crowded, and there's already a `close` function in it that you can't override. Use a different name.

This is one of the many reasons **not** to use `onxyz` attribute-style event handlers: They require that your functions be globals. Instead, use modern event handling that doesn't require that you use globals:

```
document.getElementById("img-id").addEventListener("click", function() {
    // ...your code here...
}, false);
```

Make sure the code above runs *after* the `img` element exists. *(If you have to support obsolete browsers like IE8 — or IE9-11 when they hobble themselves with [in]compatibility mode — [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799296/js-li-tag-onclick-not-working-on-ie8/23799448#23799448).)*

Example:

```js
document.getElementById("img-id").addEventListener("click", function() {
  // ...your code here...
  alert("Clicked");
}, false);
```

```html
<div style="width: 300px; height: 200px;" id="img-div">
  <img id="img-id" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4f8efc215ecc23017b42334c9b30c49b?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"  style="CURSOR:pointer;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the name "close()"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Date</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 300px; height: 200px;" id="img-div" >
    <img id="img-id"  src="resources/01.jpg" width="200px" height="80px"  style="CURSOR:pointer;" onclick="closing();"> 
</div>
<script  type="text/javascript">
    function closing(){

        console.log('js');

        alert(111);
    }

</script>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used `close()` function which is same as JavaScript's native `close()` function, so use another name as below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Date</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 300px; height: 200px;" id="img-div" >
    <img id="img-id"  src="resources/01.jpg" width="200px" height="80px"  style="CURSOR:pointer;" onClick="close_function();"/> 
</div>
<script  type="text/javascript">
    function close_function(){

        console.log('js');

        alert(111);
    }

</script>
</body>
<html>
```