# Simple onclick fails to remove child node

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  var oBtn = document.getElementById('btn1');
  var oTxt = document.getElementById('txt1');
  var oUl = document.getElementById('ul1');
  var aA = [];

  oBtn.onclick = function() {
    var oLi = document.createElement('li');
    var aLi = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

    // add <a> to li
    oLi.innerHTML = oTxt.value + ' <a href="javascript:;">delete</a>';

    if (aLi.length > 0) {
      oUl.insertBefore(oLi, aLi[0]);
    } else {
      oUl.appendChild(oLi);
    }

    // everytime add an li, add <a> which is in <li> to aA
    aA.push(oLi.children[0]);
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < aA.length; i++) {
    aA[i].onclick = function() {
      oUl.removeChild(this.parentNode);
    }
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <input id='txt1' type="text" />

  <!-- Add an li element -->
  <input id="btn1" type="button" value="Add li" />
  <ul id="ul1">
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi everyone, I'm a javascript beginner, and I have a trouble in click event, following is my problem:

When I click `oBtn.onclick`, it create an `li` element to `ul`, then `innerHTML` of `li` contains tag "a" and be pushed to an array named aA.

However, in `aA[i].onclick`, it doesn't work, so what is the problem in my code?

Comment: There's no attempt to remove any elements in your click handler. The loop that contains a `removeChild` call will never call it, as at that point `aA` is empty, so the body of the loop never gets executed.

Comment: it's because you bind the anchor click before it is created

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to achieve. State clearly: What code is supposed to do what, what you're doing, what results you're seeing, and what results you expected to see instead.

Comment: @Pete: I just completely misread that loop, missed the `onclick` entirely (I never use it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never doing anything to connect an event handler on the `a` element's `click` event. See comments:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var oBtn = document.getElementById('btn1');
  var oTxt = document.getElementById('txt1');
  var oUl = document.getElementById('ul1');
  var aA = [];

  oBtn.onclick = function() {
    var oLi = document.createElement('li');
    var aLi = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

    // Create deletion link and hook it up
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = "javascript:;";
    a.innerHTML = "delete";
    a.onclick = deleteOnClick;

    // add text and <a> to li
    // note the use of createTextNode, in case the user types something with < in it
    oLi.appendChild(document.createTextNode(oTxt.value + " "));
    oLi.appendChild(a);

    // Add at the beginning of the list
    oUl.insertBefore(oLi, oUl.firstChild);

    // everytime add an li, add <a> which is in <li> to aA
    aA.push(oLi.children[0]);
  };
  
  // Called by click handler to delete the clicked' element's parent
  function deleteOnClick() {
    var parent = this.parentNode;
    parent.parentNode.removeChild(parent);
  }
};
```

```html
<input id='txt1' type="text" />

  <!-- Add an li element -->
  <input id="btn1" type="button" value="Add li" />
  <ul id="ul1">
  </ul>
```

---

Some other notes:

1. `onclick` is quick and easy, but it doesn't play nicely with others. Look at using modern event handling (`addEventListner`). If you need to support obsolete browsers like IE8, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23799448/157247) for a function that works even when `addEventListener` is missing.
2. Loading scripts in `head` (without using `async` or `defer`) is poor practice. Barring a good reason to do something else, put them at the end of the document body, just before the closing `</body>` tag.
3. The `load` event on `window` happens **very** late in the page load process, waiting until after all images and stylesheets and other external resources have finished loading. Barring a good reason to wait that long, hook up handlers earlier. If you put your script at the end of the `body` (see #2), you can do it right there in the top level of the script.
4. Wrapping your code in a scoping function like this:

   ```
   (function() {
       // ...your code here...
   })();
   ```

   will save you a fair bit of heartache, since otherwise all of your top-level variables and functions are globals. The global namespace is already far too crowded, making conflicts a problem.
5. Look into the idea of *event delegation* for your `delete` handlers. You can handle the click on the `ul` element, and then check to see if it passed through your `a` element en route when bubbling. This lets you not worry about hooking it up later when you create the delete link.

Comment: Thank for your response!  In your code, it seems that there are no order problem in code!  I learn a lot from your code, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the anchor click event after the anchor is created - you try to bind it before they are created

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var oBtn = document.getElementById('btn1');
  var oTxt = document.getElementById('txt1');
  var oUl = document.getElementById('ul1');
  var aA = [];

  oBtn.onclick = function() {
    var oLi = document.createElement('li');
    var aLi = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

    // add <a> to li
    oLi.innerHTML = oTxt.value + ' <a href="javascript:;">delete</a>';

    if (aLi.length > 0) {
      oUl.insertBefore(oLi, aLi[0]);
    } else {
      oUl.appendChild(oLi);
    }

    // everytime add an li, add <a> which is in <li> to aA
   // aA.push(oLi.children[0]);                         <- don't think you need this array anymore
    
    // bind your anchor click here
    oLi.children[0].onclick = function() {
      oUl.removeChild(this.parentNode);
    }
  };
}
```

```html
  <input id='txt1' type="text" />

  <!-- Add an li element -->
  <input id="btn1" type="button" value="Add li" />
  <ul id="ul1">
  </ul>
```

Comment: Thank for your response! It works! 

But why oLi.children[0].onclick  is contained in oBtn.onclick, they are triggered by different button?

Comment: @nigel, because you create the `oLi.children[0]` inside the `oBtn` so you need to bind the click event when you have created the child - you can't bind it to something that hasn't been created which is why your original failed