# IE7: call is undefined on document.attachEvent function

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, attachevent

I was trying to call `.call` Function prototype method on `document.attachEvent` in IE7. But it is showing as undefined. 
I have also checked `typeof document.attachEvent`, is should show as `function` but it is `object`. 
Can someone explain it why?

```
document.attachEvent.call(this, 'onclick', function () {});
```

Getting this error

```
Error: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

Comment: Why do you need to set a specific `this` when calling `attachEvent`? Feels like an X/Y problem. I've answered Y ("What's up with `attachEvent`?) but I suspect you really need an answer to X, the thing that made you want to do this...

Comment: Hi, @T.J.Crowder, I was adding too many events at once, so don't want replicate code twice, one with `document.addEventListener` and one with `document.attachEvent`. So just assigning a local variable to these function, and adding events using `.call`. Anyway, I will find another methoda.

Comment: I'd use a wrapper method to normalize things, something like [this version of `hookEvent`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799296/js-li-tag-onclick-not-working-on-ie8/23799448#23799448), which handles the various issues with `attachEvent` (like the `"on"` part, the fact that event objects on obsolete browsers like that don't have `preventDefault` or `stopPropagation` [though they have the feature, just not the standard API], etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Host-provided functions are not required to be proper JavaScript functions, so long as they can be called. That means they aren't required to inherit from `Function.prototype` (and thus may not have `call` or `apply`, which come from `Function.prototype`) and `typeof` may not identify them as functions (because from a JavaScript perspective, while they're callable, they're not functions).

Not all obsolete browsers made functions proper functions, including IE7.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks for the info

Comment: @AndrewLi: No worries. Host-provided *objects* can be weird too. :-) But these days, modern browsers mostly provide true functions and at least *mostly* real objects.