# How to figure out who is firing the submit event?

Tags: javascript

I am having a situation where I am not able to figure out who is calling the form submit.

I have a dom like below.

```
<form method="POST" action="action.do">
<button onclick = "eventHandler()">Test</button>
</form>
```

Whenever I click on the button I see a breakpoint hit on submit and not able to figure out anything from call stack.

Need help

Comment: try `e.target` from event object

Comment: If you define as `function eventHandler(e) { ... }` see `e.target`

Comment: When you specify button tag without type attribute, it takes default as 'submit' which submits this form after  eventHandler() finished. To prevent it change type attribute of button tag.

Comment: @vvtx Brilliant. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: If what you are really asking is how to stop the form submission, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms

Answer (score 3):

In general, avoid using `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers. But if you do, call them setting `this` correctly and passing in the event; you may also want to include `return` if you want to use `return false` in the handler to prevent the default action of the event:

```
<button onclick = "return eventHandler.call(this, event)">Test</button>
<!-- --------------^^^^^^--------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^             -->
```

(Without the return, on modern browsers, you can use the `preventDefault()` method on the event object instead of returning false.)

Within the handler, `this` will refer to the element (the `button`, in this case) and the first argument will be the event object, which has other useful information.

Note that this handler does **not** handle the `submit` event. It handles a `click` event on a submit button. `submit` is an event fired at forms, not buttons.

**But**, in general I'd recommend modern event handling, which hooks up the event once the button exists:

```
var btn = document.querySelector("selector-for-the-button");
btn.addEventListener("click", eventHandler, false);
```

With that, `eventHandler` will be called with the correct `this` and passed the event object.

Note: The obsolete browsers IE8 and earlier do not have `addEventListener`. The obsolete browsers IE9-IE10 have it but pretend they don't when they're in "compatibility" mode. IE11 similarly hobbles itself when in "compatibility" mode. If you need to support any of those, you can use the `hookEvent` function [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799296/js-li-tag-onclick-not-working-on-ie8/23799448#23799448).

Or of course, use a library like jQuery, or a framework like AngularJS or React, etc., that handles those cross-browser issues for you.

Comment: @JohnHascall: Quite. There's no reason I shouldn't include that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because `type` attribute is not specified in `button` tag:

```
<button onclick = "eventHandler()">Test</button>
```

it takes default `type` as `submit`, so on click of this `button`, submits the `form` after finishing `eventHandler()` code. To make `button` not to submit form, add `type` attribute with value as `button`.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a complete code for what are you looking for:

```js
function eventHandler(e){
  console.log(e.target);
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Title</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form method="POST" action="action.do" onsubmit="return false;">
   <button onclick = "eventHandler(event)">Test</button>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```