# some function are not getting called when function are wrapped inside the self invoking function

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am using javascript for my project and in the same I had some javascript functions defined, but when I was validating the function through DOMMonster it is giving a tip that there are too many global function declaration.

To overcome that I enclosed my functions inside a self invoking function by which I was able to remove the global nature of the function. but, 2 functions which were called on the OnChange event are not firing up. can someone suggest me how to make it work inside the same.
**CODE**

```
(function(){
    function createHiddenDateField(elementName) {
        // format is DD/MM/YYYY
        var finalDate = document.getElementById(elementName + '-DD').value + '/' + document.getElementById(elementName + '-MM').value + '/' + document.getElementById(elementName + '-YYYY').value;
        document.getElementById(elementName).value = finalDate;
        if(elementName=="securityQuestionAnswerDate"){
            document.getElementById("securityQuestionAnswerDate").onchange();
        }
        return finalDate;
    }
})();
```

**CALLER :**

```
<select id="dateofbirth-DD" class="form_field date_field_select 
                    " onchange="createHiddenDateField('dateofbirth')">
                    <option value="">DD</option>
                    <option value="01">01
                    </option>
                    <option value="02">02
                    </option>
                    <option value="03">03
                    </option>
                    <option value="04">04
                    </option>
                    <option value="05">05
                    </option>
                    <option value="06">06
                    </option>
                    <option value="07">07
                    </option>
                    <option value="08">08
                    </option>
                    <option value="09">09
                    </option>
                    <option value="10">10
                    </option>
                    <option value="11">11
                    </option>
                    <option value="12">12
                    </option>
                    <option value="13">13
                    </option>
                    <option value="14">14
                    </option>
                    <option value="15">15
                    </option>
                    <option value="16">16
                    </option>
                    <option value="17">17
                    </option>
                    <option value="18">18
                    </option>
                    <option value="19">19
                    </option>
                    <option value="20">20
                    </option>
                    <option value="21">21
                    </option>
                    <option value="22">22
                    </option>
                    <option value="23">23
                    </option>
                    <option value="24">24
                    </option>
                    <option value="25">25
                    </option>
                    <option value="26">26
                    </option>
                    <option value="27">27
                    </option>
                    <option value="28">28
                    </option>
                    <option value="29">29
                    </option>
                    <option value="30">30
                    </option>
                    <option value="31">31
                    </option>
                </select>
```

Comment: you defined a function but missed to call it createHiddenDateField(arg)

Comment: @Sharmila  I added the code from where I am calling the same.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder please check the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

> but, 2 functions which were called on the OnChange event are not firing up

Functions hooked up with `onxyz` attributes that must be globals. It's one of the many reasons not to use `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers, since globals are a Bad Thing™.

Instead, hook up your handler using modern event handling, e.g.:

```
document.getElementById("dateofbirth-DD").addEventListener(
    "click",
    function() {
        createHiddenDateField('dateofbirth');
    },
    false
);
```

If you have to support obsolete browsers that don't support `addEventListener`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799296/js-li-tag-onclick-not-working-on-ie8/23799448#23799448) for a function that handles them for you.

Answer (score -1):

try use get() to do this and maybe use something like jquery or angularjs 
you can save a good time ! 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getdate.asp

Comment: and replace your select for datapiker      https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/