# Passing Values from input to constructor function that returns a object

Tags: javascript, oop

**Goal**: 
I'm trying to pass values from input to constructor function that returns an object

**Problem**:
 All I get in return is "undefined" 
I think it may have to do with my onclick that is on my button maybe I'm not calling it right. I'm really not sure. I have looked all over the internet an can't find the answer.

JavaScript

```
var name = document.getElementById('inputValueName').value;
var age = document.getElementById('inputValueAge').value;
var state = document.getElementById('inputValueState').value;

function person(name, age, state) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.state = state;
}
var NewPerson = new person(name, age, state);

console.log(NewPerson);
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="inputValueName">
<input type="text" id="inputValueAge">
<input type="text" id="inputValueState">
<button id="btn" onclick="person();">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting `undefined` for `name`, `age`, and `state` within `peron` because you're not passing `person` anything when you click your button:

```
<button id="btn" onclick="person();">Add</button>
<!-- Where are the arguments? ---^            -->
```

(When calling `person` that way, you'll also get back `undefined` as the result of the call, since you haven't used `new` and `person` doesn't have a `return x` statement. But I assume you mean the parameters, since you're not looking at the return value.)

Your JavaScript code showing you calling it elsewhere is correct (other than getting standard practices around capitalization in JavaScript names<sup>1</sup>):

```
var NewPerson = new person(name, age, state);
```

If you wrapped up all your JavaScript code (getting the values, calling `new person`, etc.) into a new function, say `createPerson`, and called that instead, it would largely work:

```js
function createPerson() {
  var name = document.getElementById('inputValueName').value;
  var age = document.getElementById('inputValueAge').value;
  var state = document.getElementById('inputValueState').value;

  function person(name, age, state) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.age = age;
    this.state = state;
  }
  var NewPerson = new person(name, age, state);

  console.log(NewPerson);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputValueName">
<input type="text" id="inputValueAge">
<input type="text" id="inputValueState">
<button id="btn" onclick="createPerson();">Add</button>
```

---

<sup>1</sup> You're obviously free to do what you like in your own code, but overwhelmingly, the convention in JavaScript is that *constructor* functions (ones you call via `new`) start with a capital letter, and basically no other variables do. So it would be `Person` (not `person`), for the constructor, and `newPerson` (not `NewPerson`) for the variable referencing the new person.

---

Side note: `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers are handy for quick-and-dirty mockups, but they have several problems, not least that the functions they call have to be globals, and globals are a Bad Thing™. Make sure you familiarize yourself with modern event handling for use in real apps, `addEventListener` and the like.

Comment: +1, but I think your first sentence is wrong because he didn't specify the `new` keyword before `person`

Comment: @smarber: Depends on where he/she was getting `undefined`. I was thinking he/she meant within the function as the value of the parameters `name` and such, since he/she's not using the return value, so wouldn't be seeing the `undefined` that calling `person` without `new` would result in. I can clarify it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Could you give me some good reading on modern usages of event handing?  Thanks for the feedback I will take your advise to heart

Comment: @CoryKelly: See [this page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and if you need to support obsolete browsers, see also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799296/js-li-tag-onclick-not-working-on-ie8/23799448#23799448) here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't pass any parameters to `person()` in your click handler.

Try the following:

```
function person(name, age, state) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.state = state;
}

function createPerson () {
    var name = document.getElementById('inputValueName').value;
    var age = document.getElementById('inputValueAge').value;
    var state = document.getElementById('inputValueState').value;

    var NewPerson = new person(name, age, state);
    return NewPerson;
}
```

HTML

```
<button id="btn" onclick="createPerson();">Add</button>
```

Comment: return to onclick? what should that do? may console.log(createPerson())