# Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am receiving an error on IE 8-7 saying that Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener' when I used the code below. Does anyone know how I can make the code below compatible with IE8-7? thanks

```
 document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function () {
  ["A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6", "A1_flip", 

  ].forEach(function(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).checked = false;
  });
  return false;
})
```

Comment: You've tagged your question jQuery, but you're not using any jQuery in the question. This issue is one of the things people use jQuery for.

Comment: what kind of element have this id? 
You tagged you question as HTML you should share your html code also

Comment: Please take care to tag correctly. This question has nothing to do with any of these tags: [tag:css3], [tag:function], [tag:frontend], or [tag:html]. It **does** have to do with [tag:javascript].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because they don't support `addEventListener`. See [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799296/js-li-tag-onclick-not-working-on-ie8) for details.

But since you've said you're using jQuery, you can...use jQuery to get around this issue:

```
$('#clear').on('click', function () {
  ["A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6", "A1_flip"
  ].forEach(function(id) {
    $("#" + id).prop("checked", false);
  });
  return false;
});
```

or actually, we can be a bit more direct:

```
$('#clear').on('click', function () {
  $("#" + ["A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6", "A1_flip"].join(", #")).prop("checked", false);
  return false;
});
```

...which works by building a selector string from the array.

I just realized I'm assuming the array's contents vary. If they don't, if you *literally* just want those specific elements:

```
$('#clear').on('click', function () {
  $("#A1, #A2, #A3, #A4, #A5, #A6, #A1_flip").prop("checked", false);
  return false;
});
```

...or better yet, give them a common `class` and use

```
$('#clear').on('click', function () {
  $(".the-class").prop("checked", false);
  return false;
});
```

---

If you *don't* use jQuery and just mis-tagged it, see the linked question above. One of the answers there is mine, providing a `hookEvent` function that deals with cross-browser event handling:

```
var hookEvent = (function() {
    var div;

    // The function we use on standard-compliant browsers
    function standardHookEvent(element, eventName, handler) {
        element.addEventListener(eventName, handler, false);
        return element;
    }

    // The function we use on browsers with the previous Microsoft-specific mechanism
    function oldIEHookEvent(element, eventName, handler) {
        element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, function(e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            e.preventDefault = oldIEPreventDefault;
            e.stopPropagation = oldIEStopPropagation;
            handler.call(element, e);
        });
        return element;
    }

    // Polyfill for preventDefault on old IE
    function oldIEPreventDefault() {
        this.returnValue = false;
    }

    // Polyfill for stopPropagation on old IE
    function oldIEStopPropagation() {
        this.cancelBubble = true;
    }

    // Return the appropriate function; we don't rely on document.body
    // here just in case someone wants to use this within the head
    div = document.createElement('div');
    if (div.addEventListener) {
        div = undefined;
        return standardHookEvent;
    }
    if (div.attachEvent) {
        div = undefined;
        return oldIEHookEvent;
    }
    throw "Neither modern event mechanism (addEventListener nor attachEvent) is supported by this browser.";
})();
```

Then:

```
hookEvent(document.getElementById('clear'), 'click', function(e) {
  ["A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6", "A1_flip"
  ].forEach(function(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).prop("checked", false);
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, the jQuery code. The code allowed me to run the page on IE8. However, everything worked except the following "Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'" in IE8. Is there another code I can use instead of .forEach? Thank you for your time and explanation, it was very helpful.

Comment: @user7293417: Ah, good old IE8, which hasn't gone away yet. :-) See [this question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript) for all the ways you can loop through an array. :-) **But**, see also updates in the jQuery part of the answer above, you can avoid looping through the array in your code entirely -- and possibly even avoid having the array entirely. Enjoy! :-)

Comment: Thank you, however, I am a bit confused. I tried using                                                                      $.each(e,function(id){
  $("#" + id).prop("checked", false);
}         The effect I conducted is clearing checkboxes. It could not clear with this code unless I add a forEach. However, In the example link, am I suppose to use for-in, for of, or an iterator explicitly ? I apologize for asking an abundance amount of questions/my misunderstanding. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @user7293417: Did you see the updates to the answer saying you don't need to use a loop at all?

Answer (score 1):

Support for [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) function isn't available in older versions of Internet Explorer (i.e. 7-8), so you won't be able to use it on the browsers you are attempting to target.

You could consider wiring this up using jQuery's [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function, assuming you are using a version of jQuery that is designed to target older browsers as it will generally have the necessary fallbacks to support it.

```
$('#clear').on('click', function () {
   var elements = ["A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6", "A1_flip"];
   elements.forEach(function(id) {
         $("#" + id).prop("checked", false);
   });
   return false;
})
```

Comment: IE9+ have `addEventListener` when they're not in (in)compatibility mode.

Comment: Thanks T.J. I went off of a quick "caniuse" reference and it failed to have anything besides IE 11 listed on it. I've updated the response to be a bit more accurate in those regards.

Comment: You have to click "Show All" on caniuse to see obsolete browsers.

Comment: Thanks for your time, and the code explanation. This was very useful. Everything worked well. I am only having an issue in IE 8 saying   Objects doesnt support property or method 'forEach'    I may have to replace 'forEach' with a different code.

Comment: Correct, the `Array.forEach()` function wasn't supported until IE 9.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a better compatibility to obsolete browsers plus not really all new features of jQuery are needed. You might consider just switch to jQuery 1.1X(currently 1.12). It will save you lots of time from handling compatible issues.

ref: [jQuery - Browser support](https://jquery.com/browser-support/)