# Vanilla JavaScript instead of jQuery - ready, on, click and end selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I have in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).on('click', "[id$='someId']", function () {
      console.log($(this).val());
   })
})
```

How can I write it in pure JavaScript?

> $(document).ready(function()

Should I use "ready" in pure JavaScript?

> $(document).on

How can I use "on"? I have to add dynamic elements, so in jQuery I must use "on".

I would like write this in accordance with ES6.

Comment: Look up [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: *"Pure JavaScript instead of jQuery"* ***sigh*** There's nothing impure about your JavaScript if you use jQuery or any other library. What you mean is, how can I do this with the [DOM](https://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR) instead of jQuery? (The **language**, JavaScript, is the same regardless.)

Comment: What @Phylogenesis said. And if you need to support obsolete browsers like IE8 that don't have it, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23799448/157247) has a version for you with fallback.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder why duplicate? The question of "ready" was just an addition. The most important was "on" and selector.

Comment: *"How can I write it in pure JavaScript? `$(document).ready(function()`"* quite clearly asks what the linked question's answers answer. That's the problem with unfocussed questions. In any case, the `on` thing is ***trivially*** easy to find -- here on SO, and elsewhere, with the barest minimum of research. Please [search](/help/searching) and web search in future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of `on`:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.body.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target.matches("[id$='someId']")) {
      console.log(e.target.value);
    }
  });
});
```

The event delegation makes it a bit more complex, but it should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

### $(document).ready(function()

```
// DOMContentLoaded
// @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) {
  console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
});
```

### $(document).on

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  if (target.id === 'a') {
    // do something.
  } else if (target.id === 'b') {
    // do something.
  }
});
```