# Why the name of a function can not be equal to the id of an input in javascript

Tags: javascript

> Example with function name equal to the value of the input id

```js
function idade(){

var idade = document.getElementById('idade').value;

alert(idade);
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm">

Age: <input type="text" name="idade" id="idade" /></br></br>

<input type="submit" onclick="idade()" />

</form>
```

Comment: I think the function name *can* equal the id... it's your var idade within the function that's not working. The function is already a var named idade.

Comment: @arbuthnott: Nope, that's not the problem.

Comment: You are part of the site to ask questions or simply downvote? -1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can, but in that context it's being shadowed by the automatic variable created for the input element within the form.

The environment in which `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers run is effectively a series of `with` statements dumping all kinds of identifers (technically, *bindings*) into the scope where they run, like this:

```
with (document) {
    with (form) {
        with (theInput) {
            idade();
        }
    }
}
```

The form has a property on it named `idade` because the input has that `name`. So in the context where `idade()` is above, `idade` refers to that form element, not your global function.

This is one of the many reasons not to use `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers. (Another is that they can only call functions dumped into their scope like that or global functions, and globals are best avoided.)

Instead, use modern event handling via `addEventListener` (`attachEvent` on old IE). [My answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799296/js-li-tag-onclick-not-working-on-ie8/23799448#23799448) provides a cross-browser `hookEvent` function you can use if you need to support old IE.

Here's your example with `addEventListener` and making your function non-global:

```js
// Scoping function so we don't create globals
(function() {
  function idade(e) {

    var idade = document.getElementById('idade').value;

    alert(idade);
    
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  
  document.querySelector("input[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", idade);

})();
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
  Age: <input type="text" name="idade" id="idade">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

---

A few other things I fixed in that:

1. `</br>` is not a valid HTML tag. It's just `<br>` (or `<br />` if you're using XHTML, but if you were using XHTML, you would know that).
2. `input` elements are void elements, there's no need for a `/` before the `>` on them (it's allowed but ignored). Again, you're not using XHTML.
3. <s>Your `input` has no id, so `getElementById` will not find it. It has a name.</s> *(you've added it now)*

Also, in the above I had `idade` cancel the form submission, just so the form stays there.

Comment: Minor side-note about 1 in your "other things", is that using `<br />` can be helpful even when not using XHTML because it tells code editors not to expect a `</br>` and thus better handles collapsing blocks of code.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Any decent HTML editor knows about void elements. :-)

Comment: Guess Notepad++ sucks then :D In my case, it's a habit (even though I've never used X[H]TML...) and it does no harm and a little bit of good.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the id="idade" in the question code