# Javascript: Why is b1 considered undefined when o1 has a value and is equal to b1

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables

I've been trying to get variables to work with drop down options on a page. I was struggling to even get a value out of the function but managed by removing "var" from o1. Now if I type o1 into the js console on chrome i get a value for it but if I set another variable equal to it, such as b1, it comes out as undefined. I'd like to add if statements after the function using its output but they didn't work either. Not sure what i'm doing wrong...

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Options to variables</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
Options
<select id="i1" onchange="options()">
    <option selected = "true" disabled="disabled">---</option>
    <option id="1">Option 1</option>
    <option id="2">Option 2</option>
</select><br>
</form>
</body>
<script>
var o1;
function options(){
    o1 = i1.options[i1.selectedIndex].id;
    return o1;
}
var b1 = o1;
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You haven't called `options()` yet when the `b1` variable is assigned so it gets the still `undefined` value of `o1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement `var b1 = o1;` is **not inside the function**.

When the page loads you copy the value `undefined` from `o1` to `b1`.

When the `change` event fires, you write a new value to `o1` but you never change `b1`, so it remains `undefined`.

---

> Not sure what i'm doing wrong

Aside from the logic errors described above, your fundamental approach to the problem is wrong. You should read the value of the select element when you want to do something with that value.

You should not try to duplicate the information about what state it is in using a global variable. The state is reliably available from the original select element whenever you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Some notes:

1. Your code is relying on the automatic globals created when elements have an `id`. That's generally a bad idea, there's a lot going on in the global namespace and conflicts are rife. Instead, look them up with `document.getElementById`.
2. Returning a value out of the function you call from an `onxyz`-attribute-style event handler is not useful (unless you return `false`, which would prevent the default action of the event). I suggest you look into modern event handling.
3. Your `var b1 = o1;` is outside of your `options` function, so it's run when the page loads. At that time, `o1` is `undefined`, so of course `b1` is `undefined`. `o1` is given a different value **later**, when `options` is run, but that doesn't change `b1`.
4. Having `id`s on your `option` elements is unusual. The normal thing is to give them `value`s. And if you do, you can use `.value` on the `select` to get its value.

Here's an example avoiding those issues, and showing the `id` of the selected `option` element (along with the `select`'s value) in the console when you change it:

```js
// A scoping function to avoid creating globals
(function() {
  // Get the select element
  var i1 = document.getElementById("i1");
  
  // Watch for `change`
  i1.addEventListener("change", function() {
    // Show the ID of the selected option, and the select's value
    console.log("ID: " + i1.options[i1.selectedIndex].id + ", value: " + i1.value);
  });
})();
```

```html
<form>
Options
<select id="i1">
    <option selected = "true" disabled="disabled">---</option>
    <option id="1" value="one">Option 1</option>
    <option id="2" value="two">Option 2</option>
</select><br>
</form>
```

In fact, we can avoid using a variable for the select at all, since inside the event handler, the select box is available as `this`:

```js
document.getElementById("i1").addEventListener("change", function() {
    // Show the ID of the selected option, and the select's value
    console.log("ID: " + this.options[this.selectedIndex].id + ", value: " + this.value);
});
```

```html
<form>
Options
<select id="i1">
    <option selected = "true" disabled="disabled">---</option>
    <option id="1" value="one">Option 1</option>
    <option id="2" value="two">Option 2</option>
</select><br>
</form>
```

---

If you need to support obsolete browsers that don't have `addEventListener`, [my answer to this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23799448/157247) has a function you can use.