# How to force a javascript function to treat a parameter as string?

Tags: javascript

```
<script>

var id = "432.000+444";
myFunc(id);
document.write("<a onclick=\"myFunc("+id+");\" href=#>Click me</a><br>");

function myFunc(id) {
    alert(id);
}

</script>
```

myFunc(id) prints the string normally, but clicking on the element prints 876 (treats it as a number and adds 432 and 444). How can I prevent this? I want it to always be treated as a string.

Comment: This wouldn't be an issue if you wrote saner Javascript, e.g. `document.getElementById('myLink').addEventListener('click', myFunc.bind(null, id))`; `document.write`ing concatenated Javascript literals is pretty bad practice…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it in quotes:

```
document.write("<a onclick=\"myFunc('"+id+"');\" href=#>Click me</a><br>");
// ---------------------------------^------^
```

---

FWIW, I strongly advise **not** using `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers. For one thing, the functions you call from them have to be globals, which is generally not a good thing. Instead, use modern event handling (`addEventListener`, or `attachEvent` on old IE; [here's a function that handles that issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23799448/157247)) or at *least* the `onclick` *property*.

```
var id = "432.000+444";
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.onclick = myFunc.bind(link, id);
link.href = "#";
link.appendTextNode("Click me");
appropriateParentElement.appendChild(link);
appropriateParentElement.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

function myFunc(id) {
    alert(id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I tried to put it under double quotes, but it didn't work for some reason. Looks like I needed single quotes instead.

Comment: @Kidades: This is another of the many reasons not to use `onclick`-attribute-style handlers: Double quotes weren't working for you because the content of a double-quote-delimited attribute cannot contain a literal double quote. (Attribute values are HTML text, you could use `&quote;`, but it makes for really hard-to-read JavaScript.)

Comment: Double quotes can work, but you'd have to escape both the double quote and the preceding `\\ `.  It'd be a mess.  Much more readable and far less error-prone to just use single quotes.

Comment: @Amy: No, ``\`` isn't for escaping in HTML text.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap it in quotes.

```
                                    ↓      ↓
document.write("<a onclick=\"myFunc('"+id+"');\" href=#>Click me</a><br>");
```

Notice the single quotes.

Comment: 7 seconds slower, but better arrows.  I'm so conflicted.

Comment: Oooh, I like those. Note to self. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder FYI, I got them from https://unicode-table.com/en/sets/arrows-symbols/