# How to remove active class from all li elements except one that clicked?

Tags: javascript

It doesn't let me to complete slider in my mind. And I also want to note that not use JQuery. Only with JavaScript. I tried many ways, but it didn't take effect.

```js
var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
var dots = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var dot = document.createElement('li');
  dots.push(dot);
  ul.appendChild(dot);
}
dots[2].setAttribute('class', 'active');
```

```css
li {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.active {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

Here is JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/heybetov1998/camuyve2/4/

Comment: You've tagged jQuery, but there's no jQuery code in your question.

Comment: *"And I also want to note that not use JQuery."* Then **don't** tag jQuery!! I've removed it for you, along with all of the other irrelevant tags you've used.

Comment: well, you don't seem to have tried `addEventListener`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook up an event handler on the dots. Within the event handler, `this` will refer to the element on which you attached the handler. Then you can remove the class from all the others:

```js
var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
var dots = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var dot = document.createElement('li');
  dot.addEventListener("click", clickHandler); // ** Hook up the handler
  dots.push(dot);
  ul.appendChild(dot);
}
dots[2].setAttribute('class', 'active');

// Here's the handler
function clickHandler() {
  var dots = document.querySelectorAll("li");
  for (var n = 0; n < dots.length; ++n) {
    if (dots[n] !== this) {
      dots[n].className = "";
    }
  }
  this.className = "active";
}
```

```css
li {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.active {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

If you need to support obsolete browsers that don't have `addEventListener`, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23799448/157247) has a function for doing that.

That's the minimal-changes version. But there are several changes I'd look at making:

- Don't use `setAttribute` to set the `class` attribute. It fails on very old versions of IE, but more importantly, it completely replaces the classes on the element. Look at [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
- The example above hooks up an event handler to *each* dot, but if you have a lot of dots, or you add/remove them dynamically, you might be better off using *event delegation* by hooking up the handler on the container of the dots and then using `e.target` to determine which dot was clicked.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and hint :)

Answer (score 5):

Here's an event handler that will do it for you.

```
function handler(event) {
  for (const li of document.querySelectorAll("li.active")) {
    li.classList.remove("active");
  }
  event.currentTarget.classList.add("active");
}
```

I'll leave it to you to set up the event handler and figure out about legacy browser support if you wish.

Comment: Clean and nice solution when you have elements following the same structiure.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to assign a listener to the click event of the `li` element you're adding.

Within the listener function you can remove the active class for all li elements and then add it only to the one clicked using `this` to refer to it.

Use the [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property of the element to add/remove the active class from the element.

```js
var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
var dots = [];

function dotClicked() {
  dots.forEach(function(li) {
    li.classList.remove("active");
  });
  this.classList.add("active");
}

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var dot = document.createElement('li');
  dot.addEventListener("click", dotClicked);
  dots.push(dot);
  ul.appendChild(dot);
}
```

```css
li {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.active {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```