# Javascript getting id attribute of HTMLTableCellElement

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am trying to build a Minesweeper game, making the game grid out of table. I'm stuck with getting the id I set for specific cell, when I click on it. Here is the code to make the table.

```
var table = document.createElement("table");
for (var k = 0; k < twoDArray.length; k++) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    for (var l = 0; l < twoDArray[k].length; l++) {
        var cell = document.createElement("td");
        cell.textContent = twoDArray[k][l];
        cell.setAttribute("id", "" + k + "," + l + "");
        cell.setAttribute("onclick", 'clickHandler('+cell+');');
        row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    table.appendChild(row);
}
return document.getElementById("tableDiv").appendChild(table);
```

And here is the clickHandler() function:

```
function clickHandler(cell) {
    console.log(cell.getAttribute("id"));
}
```

Please, what I am doing wrong? Getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier error.

Comment: `cell.setAttribute("onclick", ...)` is not a way to set event listeners, use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use string concatenation meaningfully with a DOM element, so this is incorrect:

```
cell.setAttribute("onclick", 'clickHandler('+cell+');');
```

Moreover, there's no reason whatsoever to use a string for this. If you want to use "simplistic" event handling, assign a function to the `onclick` property:

```
cell.onclick = clickHandler;
```

To use modern event handling, use `addEventListener`:

```
cell.addEventListener(clickHandler);
```

Sadly, old IE (or IE in "pretend to be old and useless" mode, aka "compatibility mode) doesn't have `addEventListener` and you have to use `attachEvent` instead; see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23799448/157247) if you need to support old IE / useless IE.

*(Another alternative below.)*

In either case, when the handler is called, the cell you added the handler to is available via `this`, so:

```
function clickHandler() {
    console.log(this.id);
}
```

It's also available via the `currentTarget` property of the event object you receive, so this also works:

```
function clickHandler(e) {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.id);
}
```

(There's also `e.target`, which is where the event originated — so for instance, if you had `<td id="foo"><span>click me</span></td>` and hooked `click` on the `td`, if you click the `span` then `this` and `e.currentTarget` refer to the `td` and `e.target` refers to the `span`.)

But another alternative for you is to **not** hook `click` on each and every `td`, but instead hook it on the `table` and then work from `e.target`:

```
table.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
```

and

```
function clickHandler(e) {
    var td = e.target;
    while (td.tagName != "TD") {
        td = td.parentNode;
        if (!td || td == this) {
            return; // Click didn't pass through a td
        }
    }
    console.log(td.id);
}
```

---

Side note: As you can see above, `id` is a reflected property for the `id` attribute, so you can *set* the `id` using the property as well:

```
cell.id = k + "," + l;
```

Also note that the `"" +` and `+ ""` on the original version of that line are completely unnecesary; if you use `+` on a number and string, it does string concatenation, not addition, regardless of the order of the operands.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. addEventListener worked just fine, and getting id by this.id!

Comment: @Stark: See the note I just added about `addEventListener`. Someday I'll be able to stop warning people about it, but that day isn't today. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> cell.setAttribute("onclick", 'clickHandler('+cell+');');
> ```

You are converting `cell` (which is an HTML element object) into a string (which will be `"[object Object]"` so your resulting JS will look like this:

```
clickHandler([object Object]);
```

… which is JS with a syntax error in it.

You should make use of the *this* keyword instead:

```
cell.setAttribute("onclick", 'clickHandler(this);');
```

giving

```
clickHandler(this);
```

When used in the context of a click event handler, `this` is the element that was clicked on.

---

That said, using JS to generate a string that will later be evaluated as JS is simply nasty. This is a simple case, but add any more complexity and it rapidly becomes a good source of bugs and security problems.

You should use `addEventListener` and assign a function instead.

```
cell.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction(event) {
    clickHandler(this);
}
```

(Rewriting `clickHandler` to simply use `this` is probably a better bet than creating a wrapper function though).

---

Note that table cells are not designed to be interactive controls. Using them as such will create problems for people who aren't using a pointing device to interact with their computer (such as many of those using a screen reader, keyboard or breath switch).

It is generally a better idea to put a button inside the cell and make that the click target.