# How does [] attach the event listener?

Tags: javascript, event-listener

In hyperapp code base we could able to see the line:

https://github.com/hyperapp/hyperapp/blob/master/src/app.js#L135

which shows:

```
  try {
    element[name] = value
  } catch (_) {}
```

Apparently, `element` is an HTMLElement and `value` is a function! The interesting part here is that, if `name` is say for example `onclick` and `value` is a function which does prints something to the console, the above code correctly adds the event listener for `onclick`.

I was wondering whether is this a short hand for `addEventListener` or I'm wrong here?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was wondering whether is this a short hand for `addEventListener`...

No. It's the old DOM0 style event handling that predates it. If you assign a function to `element.onclick` or `element.onmouseover`, etc., it sets up that function as an event handler.

What's different about this from `addEventListener` is that only **one** function can be set up this way; if you do it a second time with a second function, it replaces the first. In contrast, `addEventListener` can be used to play nicely with others, allowing multiple handlers.

(Another difference is that the `onxyz` style worked on old IE, which didn't support `addEventListener` [but did support its Microsoft-only predecessor, `attachEvent`]. So old cross-browser code would frequently use the `onxyz`-style if playing nicely with others wasn't necessary. FWIW, if you still have to support IE8 or IE9-IE11 in their broken "compatibility mode," you can use the `hookEvent` function in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23799448/157247), which uses `addEventListener` or `attachEvent` if possible.)

Answer (score 1):

It's *sort of* a shorthand for `addEventListener` but with one major drawback: you can only have one handler.

```js
function firstHandler() {
  console.log('#1');
}

function secondHandler() {
  console.log('#2');
}

let onclickEl = document.getElementById('onclick');
let addEventListenerEl = document.getElementById('addEventListener');

// We can bind multiple event handlers using addEventListener
addEventListenerEl.addEventListener('click', firstHandler);
addEventListenerEl.addEventListener('click', secondHandler);

// But watch what happens when we do the same with onclick
onclickEl.onclick = firstHandler;
onclickEl.onclick = secondHandler;
```

```html
<button id="addEventListener">addEventListener</button>
<button id="onclick">onclick</button>
```

For this reason, in your own code, I'd suggest always using `addEventListener`.