# calling different functions from inside and outside of div

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a div inside a div. And I want to call a function on the click of outer div and another function on the click of inner div. Is it possible to do so?

```
<div onclick="function1()">
<div onclick=function2()></div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's event bubbling concept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is very much possible. And the code you have will get the job done.

*NOTE:* You need to add `event.stopPropagation()` in case you want to prevent the bubbling of the event from the inner function.

Try this out:

```js
function function1() {
  console.log("From outer div");
}

function function2(event) {
  console.log("From inner div");
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

```css
#outer-div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}

#inner-div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer-div" onclick="function1()">
  <div id="inner-div" onclick="function2(event)"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: inner div calls both the function. which is not needed

Comment: @SatishGupta Added `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent bubbling of the event from the inner function. Thanks

Comment: @dfsq It is very easy to mock someone's answer, but it would rather be more useful if you could actually point out why something wouldn't work. P.S. if you thought it was `event` that was not being passed, then I have updated the answer. I understand that Firefox doesn't pick out the event variable by itself, so it needs to be explicitly passed. However, it does work in the Webkit browsers. Anyway, that was not the point of the OP.

Comment: Well it was bad answer anyway, why not mock it, huh? Now it's better, so cheers!

Comment: @dfsq I think the whole purpose of SO is learning something new, so I would refrain from mocking something without providing an insight as to why it wouldn't work. Anyway, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is; one way to do it is the way you've done it in your question, except:

1. You need quotes around the inner `onclick` attribute value, just as you have around the outer `onclick` attribute value.
2. You probably want to pass `event` into at least the inner one:

   ```
   <div onclick="function2(event)"></div>
   ```

   and then have it call `stopPropagation` on that:

   ```
   function function2(event) {
       event.stopPropagation();
   }
   ```

   so that the click event isn't propagated to the parent (doesn't bubble any further). If the click bubbles, `function1` will be called as well.

Example:

```js
function function1() {
  console.log("function1 called");
}
function function2(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log("function2 called");
}
```

```html
<div onclick="function1()">
<div onclick="function2(event)">this div fires function2</div>
clicking here will fire function1
</div>
```

You might also consider modern event handling rather than `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers; search for examples of `addEventListener` for details; my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23799448/157247) also has a useful workaround for obsolete browsers.