# In JavaScript and HTML, how can I get the access to the <div> that the current button locates?

Tags: javascript, html

In HTML, I have

```
 <div>
      <button onclick="action()">button</button>
 </div>
```

Without giving an `ID` or `class` to the   `div` element, what can I do in JavaScript to get an access to it and use it?

Comment: Use the `closest` selector, or access the element's `parentElement` (put your Javascript in your Javascript section - putting it in HTML attributes is as bad as `eval`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `this` into `action`:

```
<button onclick="action(this)">button</button>
```

and then in action

```
function action(btn) {
    var div = btn.parentNode;
    // ...
}
```

or if you want a bit more flexibility, use the (relatively-new) `closest` method:

```
function action(btn) {
    var div = btn.closest("div");
    // ...
}
```

---

Side note: Rather than `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers, consider using modern event handling (`addEventListener`, `attachEvent` on obsolete browsers). If you have to support obsolete browsers, my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23799448/157247) provides a function you can use to deal with the lack of `addEventListener`.

Comment: Doesn't "this" refer to the button?

Comment: @ronnLee: Not if you use `onclick="action()"`, no. It does if you use modern event handling.

Comment: So, other than using it on "onclick="action()", this usually refers to the current element?

Comment: @ronnLee: Sorry, I misunderstood what you were asking in your comment and was unclear. In `onclick="action(this)"`, yes, `this` refers to the button (the element that attribute is on). But *within* `action`, `this` would not refer to the button (that's why I have you pass it in). With modern event handling, `this` within `action` would refer to the button.

Answer (score 0):

using `this` in the `onclick=action()` and then the parent is `.parentNode`
then your method would look like :

```
<div>
  <button onclick="action(this);">button</button>
</div>

function action(el) {
  console.log(el.parentNode);
}
```

but I rather prefer `.addEventListener`and for your next question then :

```js
var $el = document.getElementById("a");
$el.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  // Create a <button> element
  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  // Create a text node 
  var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
  // Append the text to <button>
  btn.appendChild(t);        
  // Append <button> to the parentNode          
  this.parentNode.appendChild(btn);
});
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="a">Button</button>
</div>
```

Also in case you wonder for a shorter version and probably introducing to the [jQuery](http://jquery.com) :

```js
;$(function(){
  $("#a").on("click", function(e) {  
    $(this).parent().append('<button>Click Me</button>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id="a">Button</button>
</div>
```

Another but not straight way to get the parent instead of `.parentNode` is `.closest()` method:

```
element.closest("div"); // also supported in jQuery
```

Returns the first ancestor of element, that is a `<div>` element:

Comment: What if i want to add another button after clicking it, do i just say "function action(e){        e.parentNode.appendChild(button);}

Comment: @ronnLee & nullqube: `e` is a very poor choice of name for that parameter, since `action` is an event handler and in most cases, an event handler accepting a parameter called `e` is receiving an Event object -- but the `action` above is **not**. *"if I want to add another button"* Yes, that would work. Just change the name of the parameter. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Grab the event then get the `currentTarget` then find the `parentNode`. Very simple way to do it.  This will work no matter which element is clicked. Please see code snippet demonstration.

```js
function getParentNode(event) {
  console.log(event.currentTarget.parentNode);
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"><button onclick="getParentNode(event)">Click</button></div>
<div id="div2"><button onclick="getParentNode(event)">Click</button></div>
```

Comment: @ronnLee  Any progress on this issue yet?

Answer (score -1):

If it is possible, pass `this` (`button`) to action. Then you can access parent by `element.parentNode`. Example: https://jsbin.com/fidufa/edit