# Stop named function from executing itself

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to build a simple webpage, which simply checks the value of the strings in two input fields, such that when the `Test` button is clicked, a previously hidden div will show the boolean value to be returned (If isomorphic return `true`, else, return `false`).

This is my code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Isomorphics App</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="header">
            <p class="title">Isomorphics</p>
            <span>&nbsp;</span>
            <p class="description">Find out if any two strings are isomorphic.</p>
            <span>&nbsp;</span>
            <p>Enter any two words (strings) in the fields below:</p>
          </div>
          <div class="input-container">
            <input class="input" id="s" placeholder="First string" />
            <input class="input" id="t" placeholder="Second string" />
            <button class="input-button" id="submit-button">Test</button>
          </div>
          <div class="isomorphic-state-container" id="isomorphic-state-container">
            <div class="isomorphic-state-holder" id="isomorphic-state-holder">
              <p class="isomorphic-state" id="isomorphic-state">ili</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
let s = document.getElementById('s').innerText;
let t = document.getElementById('t').innerText;
console.log(s);
document.getElementById('submit-button').onclick = isomorphic(s, t);
console.log(isomorphic(s, t));

function isomorphic(str1, str2) {
  if (str1.length !== str2.length) {
    alert('Please enter two strings of equal length.');
  }
  let map = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < str1.length; i++){
    let a = str1[i]; 
    let b = str2[i];
    if (typeof map[a] === 'undefined') {
      map[a] = b;
    } else if (map[a] !== b) {
      // alert(false);
      document.getElementById('isomorphic-state-container').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('isomorphic-state-holder').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      document.getElementById('isomorphic-state').innerText = 'False'
    }
    for (var key in map) {
      if (key !== a && b === map[key]) {
        // alert(false);
        document.getElementById('isomorphic-state-container').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('isomorphic-state-holder').style.backgroundColor = '#D64BFB';
        document.getElementById('isomorphic-state').innerText = 'False'
      }
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('isomorphic-state-container').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('isomorphic-state-holder').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  document.getElementById('isomorphic-state').innerText = 'True'
}
```

styles.css

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Roboto Mono;
  font-size: 16px;
}
*:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.header {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
}
.header .title {
  font-size: 36px;
}
.header .description {
  font-size: 16px;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #000000;
}
.container .content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 65%;
  width: 100%;
}
.container .content .input-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 50%;
  height: 150px;
}
.container .content .input-container .input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.container .content .input-container .input-button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.container .content .input-container .input-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.isomorphic-state-container {
  display: none;
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
}
.isomorphic-state-holder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.isomorphic-state {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

After running this code, the javascript defaults the value to `true`, and doesn't work even when I click the button. Screenshot:

[image: Page screenshot]

What should I do to make the code run only when the button is clicked? Or, is the named function causing the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
document.getElementById('submit-button').onclick = isomorphic(s, t);
```

**calls** your function and then assigns its return value to `onclick`, exactly the way `x = foo()` **calls** `foo` and assigns its result to `x`. To set a click event handler that way, you assign a *function* (not its result) to the `onclick` property, for instance:

```
document.getElementById('submit-button').onclick = function() {
    isomorphic(s, t);
};
```

(You'll also want to remove the `console.log(isomorphic(s, t));` line, since it also calls the function.)

If you want to get `s` and `t` as of when the button is clicked, instead of when the script first runs, move those lines into the click handler as well:

```
document.getElementById('submit-button').onclick = function() {
    let s = document.getElementById('s').innerText;
    let t = document.getElementById('t').innerText;
    isomorphic(s, t);
};
```

---

Better yet, use modern event handling via `addEventListener`:

```
document.getElementById('submit-button').addEventListener("click", function() {
    // ...handler code...
});
```

If you need to support obsolete browsers like IE8, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799296/js-li-tag-onclick-not-working-on-ie8/23799448#23799448) has a workaround to their lack of `addEventListener` support.

---

There are several other issues with your code, though. For instance, to get the value of an `input` element, you use its `value` property, not its `innerText` property (it doesn't have any inner text, because it's a void element). You're also not returning after your `alert` about unequal string lengths, which you probably want to do since otherwise you go ahead and run the body of the function even though you did the `alert`...